# Long range wireless keyboard / numpad (remote control a computer from a 20-30 meter distance)

Tags: microcontroller, wireless-networking, remote-control, keyboard, keypad

In order to illustrate my challenge, I'll explain what I'm trying to achieve.

I'm training a young talent in tennis, and she's a real darling. I'm trying my develope the best environment for her to train in. So for her morning sessions, I'm setting up a laptop, a projector and a web camera. Then I've installed Open Broadcast Software - a program, where I can preview the webcam stream, with a delay that I choose (usually 1 to 5 seconds, depending on the drill). The projector the projects the camera-feed onto a wall, so she can see herself, right after she has made a hit. It's awesome and she's improving heaps, because of this. So now I want to improve it...

I would like to make the system as easy to manage as possible (so her training doesn't consist of me running back and forth between the baseline and the computer). So I've purchased a wireless headset (range up to 100 meters), and activated voice-control on the computer. I've then built in commands (with the software called AutoHotKey), so I can tell the computer what to do. For instance, if I say 'Perfect Forehand One', then it'll open a video of Roger Federer performing forehands in slow motion. So if she's asking me a question on, how to do it - then I can show her, while I explain it to her.

Now to the challenge... Since I'm training her, it involves me hitting balls back and forth to her - and I get slightly winded, while I do it. When I'm slightly winded, then the voice-recognition becomes kind of bad, since the way I say the commands vary. So I'm trying to find alternative ways to remote control the computer from the baseline (distance is 20 to 30 meters away from the computer).

Ideally, I would like a wireless numpad (like this one: Wireless Number Pad N305 - http://www.logitech.com/en-gb/support/6355?crid=404&osid=14&bit=64 ), but just with a range that is three times as long - at least. It supports up to 10 meters, which isn't enough. With that numpad, then I could make shortcut-combinations with AutoHotKey, so for instance... If I press 5+6+7+0, then it would start the preview and maximize the window. Then I could make different key combinations, and memorize them.

Another idea was to control the computer with my phone, with the TeamViewer-app, but that requires an internet connection, which isn't available in the tennis-center, at the moment. I could maybe share the connection from my phone, but it seems like a clumsy solution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Feed DTMF signals into the headset and have the computer decode them. DTMF generators are a dime a dozen.

Comment: I'd suggest you to use a WiFi computer remote type app that will make your Android or iPhone a remote keyboard and mice. Such as "Remote Control Collection" app for Android.